# Android Camera scren with Strip of Gallery Below

Tags: android, android-camera

I am looking for something like when I click on the `button`, it should open the camera `View` and this `view` should be custom with a strip of gallery at bottom.

How to achieve this in `Android`?

[image]

Comment: U will need to create your own view. Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Answer (score 0):

U can use this example its as per your requirement and working fine..

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_camera.htm

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement custom camera... you can then add any kind of overlay on your custom camera preview...